# How to give optional property to function type which is having props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have created one interface in typescript which is going to be the custom type to my Another component.

```
interface Props{
  input: string | number;
  handleChange: ({name: string, continue: boolean}) => void;  
}

function Another({input, handleChange}: Props): JSX.Element {
// returning some JSX  
}
```

I want to make the `name` and `continue` parameters optional for handleChange function type. I tried with the below approach but didn't work as expected.

```
interface Props{
  input: string | number;
  handleChange: ({name?: string, continue?: boolean}) => void;  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work as expected" do you have an example of the error message? also did you mean to pass the parameters into handleChange as an object or were they meant to be individual properties? e.g. `handleChange: (name?: string, continue?: boolean) => void;`. Can you show us how you are invoking handleChange to make it more clear, might help me answer :)

Comment: I was getting error in my test cases "type "(name?: string, continue?: boolean) => void" is not assignable to "() => void"

Comment: You should share your test cases because that kind of error is going to depends on your tests and what implementation its expecting

Comment: true but @bigblind answered helped me to run those test cases. I have to pass an object as a whole to the props just like I did with `Another` component.

Comment: Thats fine, I just didnt want to try and blindly give an answer that may encourage you to pass undefined (which is often not going to be intended behaviour)

Comment: I agree with you.  I would have more accurate about my error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a name to the object as a whole, and make that optional, for instance:

```js
interface Props{
  input: string | number;
  handleChange: (arg?: {name?: string, continue?: boolean}) => void;  
}
```

now, hadneChange can be called without any parameters, or with an object, possibly having a `name` and a `continue` field.

Comment: please note that this will work without making `arg` optional, and the developer will likely not desire it to be anyway (since that more easily leads to undefined behavior)

Answer (score 0):

All credits to @bigblind. We need to pass an object as a whole as @bigblind said.

I did like the below which helped me pass my test cases.

```
interface handleChangeProps{
 name?: string;
 continue?: boolean;
}

interface Props{
  input: string | number;
  handleChange: ({name, continue}: handleChangeProps) => void;  
}
```